# Entity Framework Core Update child entities problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.NET Core 2.2. MVC project I have a master-detail form that I use for editing a PARENT table that also has a list of child entities (stored in CHILD table).

When I save the modifications on the form I first save the changes to the parent entity and then run the following method to update the corresponding child entities:

```cs
private void UpdateChildList(ParentModel model)
{
    // lists
    var listOld = _parents.Get(model.IdParent).ListChilds;
    var listNew = model.ListChilds;
    var listNewInt = from x in listNew select x.IdChild;

    // 1. remove deleted
    var deleteList = new List<int>();
    deleteList = listOld.Where(t => !listNewInt.Contains(t.IdChild)).Select(x => x.IdChild).ToList();

    foreach (var d in deleteList)
    {
        var item = listOld.Where(x => x.IdChild == l).First();
        _parents.DeleteChild(item);
    }

    // 2. update existing
    var list = from x in listNew
    where x.IdChild > 0
    select x;

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        _parents.UpdateChild(item);
    }

    // 3. add new 
    list = from x in listNew
    where x.IdChild == 0
    select x;

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        _parents.AddChild(item);
    }
}
```

**1.** deleting works OK & **3.** adding works OK, but **2.** UPDATING produces the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Child' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdChild'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Note: I'm using `service.AddScoped` to add services in my Startup class.

EDIT: I'm adding the code from my HTTPPost (in controller):

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(ParentModel model)
{
    // valid check
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /// ... some lists for dropdowns here

        return View(model);
    }

    var item = _parents.Get(model.IdParent);

    item.Field1 = model.Field1;
    // ... and other fields

    // update parent
    _parents.Update(item);

    // update Child list
    UpdateChildList(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

EDIT2: adding my code for delete/update/add child records

```cs
public void AddChild(Child item)
{
    _dbContext.Add(item);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

public void UpdateChild(Child item)
{
    _dbContext.Update(item);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

public void DeleteChild(Child item)
{
   _dbContext.Remove(item);
   _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The error tells exactly what's going on. You're trying to attach items that have already been attached in the first line. Although that's just an assumption because you don't show what happens in all these `_parentDbContext` methods.

Comment: I have added some addtional code to make my situation more clear. I'm not sure where is the problem that I'm attaching item that are already attached - is an update operation an 'attach'? Could it be that the problem is that I have parent & child CRUD operation in the same interface/repository?

Comment: Please provide *all relevant code*.  `DeleteChild()`, `UpdateChild()` and `AddChild()` are not entity framework methods.

Comment: What is your logic to update an item? Why did you call `1. remove deleted`, `// 2. update existing` and `// 3. add new` for the same list? For updating, you may consider try automapper to map viewmodel to entity and update the item.

Comment: @Erik Philips: I added the relevant code to my post

Comment: @Tao Zhou: I thought it was not possible to update a parent entity and also simultaneously its child entities list in EF?

Comment: You could update the parent with chid directly.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but I get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Child' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdChild'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't prepare a demo, because this project is part of a larger solution and all tied to our database/domain

Comment: For a workaround I will not remove child records from DB, but just mark them as "Deleted=true". This will work

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
var listOld = _parents.Get(model.IdParent).ListChilds;
```

Entity Framework retrieves information from the context and begin tracking this entities and when you do:

```
_parents.UpdateChild(item);
```

you invoke:

```
_dbContext.Update(item);
```

Which on other side tries to attaches this entity to a context again and sets its `EntityState` to `Modified` and so you get an exception.

When you retrieve information from the database and then work with it, you are in the so called "Connected scenario" and Entity Framework context track all retrieved entities. As soon as you modify some data of this entities, the context sets its `EntityState` to `Modified` because of modification is performed. So, then you can call the `SaveChanges()` method, it builds and executes Update statement in the database.

So you have two options:

1. Add `.AsNoTracking()` in your retrieval query so you will do a no tracking queries and no entities will be added to the db context respectively. Then you will work in "Disconnected scenario" and you can use db context `Update()` method;
2. Change the `UpdateChild` method by mapping field by field so changing a field in the entity will set it's `EntityState` to `Modified`. Then remove `_dbContext.Update(item)` at all because `SaveChanges()` will do the entire work.

Another thing to mention - doing a `SaveChanges()` in a loop is generally not a good idea. This mean that you send (n) queries to database, where (n) is the number of the records.

Comment: thank you. I added the AsNoTracking() to "Get" Parent Entity and the update works.
*looping thru records and doing a Save was because I was searchin for a workaround since I couldnt get the Update to work

Comment: EDIT: solution doesn't quite work. It does work on updating changed items in the child list, it also adds new items in the child list, but it does not delete removed items from the child list. Do I still have to check for deleted items manually (like in my code above) and delete in a loop ?

Comment: What error do you get? I would pass my list in RemoveRange() method. But it's not a big problem if you stick to Remove() in loop but with SaveChanges() after the loop. Remove and RemoveRange works in disconnected scenario so they will attach the specified entity to the DbContext with deleted state and start tracking them. So after SaveChanges() they will do work for you.

Comment: I get no error, just the child records (removed by user) dont get deleted in the database. Until I find a better solution, I'll delete the child entities manually

Comment: @TheMixy Did you find a better solution since you had this issue?

Comment: @Dairon: this was quite some time ago, so I don't remember exactly, but I think the main problem with my code was that I was updating child records to the DB. When I changed the code to just update/insert the parent record (with attached child records) everything worked as expected. Let me know, if you had a more specific part of my code in mind...